# Why I am getting error message when using Yii CActiveForm::validate() with array

Tags: ajax, yii

I have a problem related to `CActiveForm::validate()`. I have a form and and sending data to database using Ajax, my form contains a multiple selectable drop-down list. In data saving section of controller produced the following error initially

```
mb_strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (.../framework/validators/CStringValidator.php:84)
```

and after updating framework to newer version, that error gone, and got the below validation message instead.

```
Category Ids is invalid.
```

If the form is fully filled(I mean all the rules in the model satisfied), it will not produce any such bug or error message.

controller action

```
public function actionCompany() {
        $model = new Company;
        if (isset($_POST['Company'])) {
            $model->attributes = $_POST['Company'];
            $category_ids = "";
            if (is_array($_POST['Company']['category_ids']))
                $category_ids = implode(',', $_POST['Company']['category_ids']);
            $model->category_ids = $category_ids;
            if ($model->validate()) {
                /*$temp = Company::model()->findByPK($model->id);
                if ($temp !== null) {
                    $model = $temp;
                }*/
                $model->save();
                echo CJSON::encode(array('status' => 'success'));
                Yii::app()->end();
            } else {
                $error = CActiveForm::validate($model);
                if ($error != '[]')
                    echo $error;
            }
        }
    }
```

Model rules

```
public function rules()
    {

        return array(
            array('...., category_ids,...', 'required'),
            array('..., category_ids, ...', 'length', 'max'=>255),
            ....
            .....
            array('...., category_ids,...', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
        );
    }
```

What is actually I'm missing?

Comment: 1) What does the model's `rules()` method look like? 2) Storing multiple values in a single DB column is really bad design and will cause you a lot of problems in the future.

Comment: 1.Updated my question.
2. But I don't feel like for storing the categories needs different table in this case, If Iam going for that;it'll results a table contains lots of records, with repeated company_id ?
I'm not sure.. feels like this is good na?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your current problem. If you fill out the form properly, you get no errors, if you fill it out incorrectly, you get that error message... where's the issue?

Comment: Multiple records in one field is really bad for anything other than dumb storage - for starters, you cannot effectively search for companies associated with specific categories, or join the categories table and preload the categories with the company info.

Comment: @DCoder, I mean `if ($model->validate())` this line doesn't produce any errors, but `$error = CActiveForm::validate($model);` produce that error, means if all the fields entered properly the else part doesnt execute, but whenever that else part executes that error ocuures! so I figured out the bug/error with `CActiveForm::validate($model);`

Comment: Er, if `validate()` fails, that means your model does not meet the requirements from one of the validation rules, and `CActiveForm::validate()` then returns the error message for the first failed requirement. Sounds like expected behavior to me.

Comment: :( How can I clear this out.. let me try. for example, say my form has 3 fields, two are required, one is multi selectable(required) and it gives an array to controller action, whenever I'm filling out all the fields no issues, but whenever i miss other required field it produce validation messages including that multiple selectable,even if it has selections, I echoed the model and found out value exists for that attribute, so my question is even if it has value why it produce invalid validation message??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36753/discussion-between-kannan-and-dcoder)

Comment: OK, now I get your problem. But I have no ideas what could cause it... sorry.

Comment: Figured it out. By default, [`CActiveForm::validate()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveForm#validate-detail) loads the model attributes from `$_POST` and overrides current attribute values, thus destroying your work. Pass `false` as the third argument to avoid this.

Comment: Oh! thanks a lot @DCoder..... actually I just came through this now, print_rd model in both cases and saw that array again before CActiveForm::validate($model);, can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, [`CActiveForm::validate($model)`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveForm#validate-detail) loads the model attributes from `$_POST` and overrides current attribute values, thus destroying your transformed values. Pass `false` as the third argument to avoid this.